# SQL issue with checkout times

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am getting data from a punching machine like this:

**Table `checkinout`**:

```
userID             checktime                     checktype 

100       2017-07-18 06:53:47.000                    I
100       2017-07-18 06:54:47.000                    I
102       2017-07-18 06:55:47.000                    I
104       2017-07-18 06:57:47.000                    I
100       2017-07-18 16:53:47.000                    O
100       2017-07-18 16:53:47.000                    O
102       2017-07-18 16:57:47.000                    O
104       2017-07-18 16:58:47.000                    O
100       2017-07-18 17:53:47.000                    O
```

I want this like:

```
 userID          checkIN time                      checkouttime        tothours   
    100       2017-07-18 06:53:47.000         2017-07-18 17:53:47.000     8.50
    102       2017-07-18 06:55:47.000         2017-07-18 16:57:47.000     9.30
    104       2017-07-18 06:57:47.000         2017-07-18 16:58:47.000     8.50
```

I used lots of queries, but nothing is working.

This is my query:

```
 DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    UserID INT,
    Checktime DATETIME,
    CheckStatus CHAR(1)
)

insert into @temp (UserID, Checktime, CheckStatus) 
  (SELECT BADGENUMBER,CHECKTIME,CHECKTYPE
    FROM CHECKINOUT join USERINFO on CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID where BADGENUMBER ='5969')

SELECT  UserID,
        CAST(I.CheckTime AS DATE) AS [Date],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.CheckTime, 108) AS CheckIn,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), O.CheckTime, 108) AS CheckOut,
        CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,I.checkTime,O.CheckTime)/60.0 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) [Hours]
FROM @temp I
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1    Checktime,
                                CheckStatus
                FROM @temp t
                WHERE       t.UserID = I.UserID
                        AND t.Checktime > I.Checktime
                ORDER BY t.Checktime
            ) O
WHERE I.CheckStatus = 'I'
  AND O.CheckStatus = 'O'.........
```

This also:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    UserID INT,
    Checktime DATETIME,
    CheckStatus CHAR(1)
)

insert into @temp (UserID, Checktime, CheckStatus) 
  (SELECT BADGENUMBER,CHECKTIME,CHECKTYPE
    FROM CHECKINOUT join USERINFO on CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID where BADGENUMBER ='6079' )

SELECT 
      t.UserID
    , [Date] = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckIn))
    , CheckIn = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckIn, 108)
    , CheckOut = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.CheckOut, 108)
    , [Hours] = CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.CheckIn, t.CheckOut) / 60. AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM (
    SELECT 
          t.UserID
        , CheckIn = t.Checktime
        , CheckOut = r.Checktime
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserID, r.Checktime ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM @temp t
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM @temp t2
        WHERE t2.UserID = t.UserID
            AND t2.Checktime > t.Checktime
            AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.Checktime)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t2.Checktime))
            AND t2.CheckStatus = 'O'
        ORDER BY t2.Checktime
    ) r
    WHERE t.CheckStatus = 'I'
) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1.......
```

Comment: Can you explain how you calculate totalhours?

Comment: checkout time - checkintime

Comment: in my qus i just did sample

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: And you have no primary key, which may prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to find diff between min checkin time (where checktype = 1) and max checkout time (where checktype = 0)

```
select userID,
    min_date,
    max_date,
    (max_date - min_date) diff
from (
    select distinct userID,
        (
            select min(checktime) 
            from checkinout t2
            where t1.userID = t2.userID
                and t2.checktype = 1
        ) min_date,
        (
            select max(checktime) 
            from checkinout t3
            where t1.userID = t3.userID
                and t3.checktype = 0
        ) max_date
    from checkinout t1
    )
order by userID
```

Comment: i got this error  Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: i am using mssql 2012 server

Comment: try it without `order by`, or put it in the end

Comment: still not working userID,
    min_date,
    max_date,
    (max_date - min_date) diff are shows error