# zkattendance sql checkin/out issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to convert like this

```
 userid     checkin time    checkout time   date
 -----------------------------------------------------
    1          7:00am          7:00pm       6/6/2018
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are various ways to achieve this  1) Use pivot, 2) use temp table 3) Use sub query try something at your end and let us know if you facing the problem in that

Comment: can you give me a model script

Comment: your desire output do not match images.please show suitable output ?

Comment: i want like that not exact, just i want intime and outtime in the same row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL issue with checkout times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272297/sql-issue-with-checkout-times)

Comment: A year ago you ask the same question

Comment: still no answer.

Comment: Select USERID
      ,CHECKTIME
      ,CHECKTYPE
FROM [att].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
Pivot 
(
    CHECKTIME for CHECKTYPE in ([I],[O])
) as PivotTable          (this code getting error   )   ---> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer thanks all

Select USERID
      ,I,O
FROM [att].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT] 
Pivot 
(
     Min(CHECKTIME) For CHECKTYPE in (I,O)
)as PivotTable where I Between '2018-05-26' AND '2018-06-26'